# How to create var in Javascript and access in MVC razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Javascript

```
 function Content(data) {
        var array = data.split(',');

    var id = array[0]; //I want to save this var and make it 
                       //accessible in the below razor code in the forloop. 
 }

@foreach (Chart item in Model)
 {
    @if(id -- this var is taken from the top javascript.) { 
        <tr>
           <td>                              
               @item.Description
           </td>
        </tr>
    } else { }
 }
```

As above I want to create a variable or some entity which is set in Javascript which can then be called in razor in the foreach loop.

Comment: Your loop is running on the server-side, so it doesn't have access to client-side variables (Javascript) unless you send them back.

Comment: What you are doing doesn't make sense. If you are trying to add a new row by splitting data that you have server side then do it server side. otherwise do the whole thing client side.

Answer (score 0):

Your Chart item model should have the id...

Comment: But I have another loop before which already displays the items, with the javascript i want to remove the item which the user has selected from the loop before.

Answer (score 0):

Your can do it, only through ajax request.

in the client side use jQuery $.ajax

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public void ActionName(bool id)
        {
    any actions
           ViewBag.id=id
           return View();
        }
```

in view:

```
@foreach (Chart item in Model)
 {
    @if(ViewBug.id) { 
        <tr>
           <td>                              
               @item.Description
           </td>
        </tr>
    } else { }
 }
```